# How to extract data from string value using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Hello I have the following string:

```
Country number Time Status USA B30111 11:15 ARRIVED PARIS NC0120 14:40 ON TIME DUBAI RA007 14:45 ON TIME
```

I need to extract following info:

```
country = USA
number = B30111
time = 11:15
status = ARRIVED

country = PARIS
number = NC0120
time = 14:40
status = ON TIME
```

How can I use regex to extract the above data from it?

Comment: In the first place You can extract the first just splitting by spaces, or do you need to use regex?

Comment: This looks much more like a CSV-type file, which you should be using existing parsers with.

Comment: Given your rep is in 4 digits this question shows no research effort. You should know this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?: (\w+) ([\w\d]+) (\d+\:\d+) (ARRIVED|ON TIME))
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jma1PN/1)

As status can hold more than one word therefore it is not possible to distinct it from the next country that appears, therefore you must append all the possible status as or| in the  regex

**Java Source:**

```
final String regex = "(?: (\\w+) ([\\w\\d]+) (\\d+\\:\\d+) (ARRIVED|ON TIME))";
final String string = "Country number Time Status USA B30111 11:15 ARRIVED PARIS NC0120 14:40 ON TIME DUBAI RA007 14:45 ON TIME\n\n\n";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("country =" + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("number =" + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("time =" + matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println("status =" + matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println("");
}
```

**output**

```
country =USA
number =B30111
time =11:15
status =ARRIVED

country =PARIS
number =NC0120
time =14:40
status =ON TIME

country =DUBAI
number =RA007
time =14:45
status =ON TIME
```

Comment: wow..I almost thought that it is not possible and that easy. But damn. You did it..Great..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you create an array based on split function, you will have each words in that array.

```
String[] splitted = str.split(" ");
```

Then to check, try this:-

```
for(String test:splitted){
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

This looks more like a CSV file.